# How to add a directory into almost a hundred of Eclipse run configurations?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, junit

I have many projects, unit tests etc. Almost a hundred and I am not joking.
Clicking 'Run Configurations', 'Classpath', 'Advanced', 'Add Folder' a hundred times is not what I would be glad to do. Is there any quicker way like Ctrl-A and then once. Well, it does not work with Crtl-A though...

Answer (score 0):

You could save the Run Configuration to a launch file.  Afterwards you can edit this file manually or programmatically.  This might be a little easier than clicking...

Answer (score 0):

Your Run Configurations are saved as `.launch` files in a subfolder of your workspace:

```
<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core\.launches
```

You can easily find/replace what you want in those file using a good text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your Eclipse workspace, in your `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/*.launch` files. These are XML file which define your launch. Edit them with a text editor, and then restart Eclipse.

You'll need to change the org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH entry.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launchconfig">
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_PATHS">
<listEntry value="/project/src/test/java/xx/yy/zz/FichierExportImplTest.java"/>
</listAttribute>
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_TYPES">
<listEntry value="1"/>
</listAttribute>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.CONTAINER" value=""/>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.KEEPRUNNING_ATTR" value="false"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.TESTNAME" value=""/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.TEST_KIND" value="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.loader.junit3"/>
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH">
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry containerPath=&quot;org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER&quot; path=&quot;1&quot; type=&quot;4&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry path=&quot;3&quot; projectName=&quot;SIBAT_BATCH_EXPORTS&quot; type=&quot;1&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry containerPath=&quot;org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER&quot; path=&quot;3&quot; type=&quot;4&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry internalArchive=&quot;/other/conf/dev&quot; path=&quot;3&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
</listAttribute>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH_PROVIDER" value="org.maven.ide.eclipse.launchconfig.classpathProvider"/>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.DEFAULT_CLASSPATH" value="false"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.MAIN_TYPE" value="xx.yy.zz.FichierExportImplTest"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROJECT_ATTR" value="SIBAT_BATCH_EXPORTS"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.SOURCE_PATH_PROVIDER" value="org.maven.ide.eclipse.launchconfig.sourcepathProvider"/>
</launchConfiguration>
```